# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'repeated'

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I am using the google cloud vm instance for developing my custom object detector- TENSORFLOW object detection API. I am using pretrained model
:[faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_atrous_coco](http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_atrous_coco_2018_01_28.tar.gz).

After creating all the necessary TFrecord files for input and configuring the object_detection pipeline config files, i used the following command for training:

```
python train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training /                                                 
--pipeline_config_path=training/faster_rcnn_custom.config
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 184, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "train.py", line 180, in main
    graph_hook_fn=graph_rewriter_fn)
  File "/opt/models/research/object_detection/trainer.py", line 274, in train
    train_config.prefetch_queue_capacity, data_augmentation_options)
  File "/opt/models/research/object_detection/trainer.py", line 59, in create_input_queue
    tensor_dict = create_tensor_dict_fn()
  File "train.py", line 121, in get_next
    dataset_builder.build(config)).get_next()
  File "/opt/models/research/object_detection/builders/dataset_builder.py", line 176, in build
    num_additional_channels=num_additional_channels)
  File "/opt/models/research/object_detection/data_decoders/tf_example_decoder.py", line 204, in __init__
    repeated=True)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'repeated'
```

How should i fix the error? i am quite new into this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I followed the instructions of creating the raccoon detection model from here:https://github.com/datitran/raccoon_dataset?files=1

Please help me resolve the issue.

Comment: Same issue were you able to figure it out

Comment: No, but I was ultimately able to train my model following a different approach. I trained using Google Cloud Jobs . Followed the instructions from here: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_on_cloud.md

Answer (score 0):

Check the correctness of your command and if the config file is in correct relative nested directory. I see there is a space between "training /" it should be "training/"

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is the error is due to the incompatibility of file tf_example_decoder.py with the Tensorflow installed. Try removing that argument. Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue. i had older tensorflow installed and trying to use new models, upgrading tensorflow solved my problem.